# Show notification when beacon is in region

Tags: swift3, ibeacon

I want to show a single notification when a beacons enters the region. I used the following code:

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if region is CLBeaconRegion {
        BeaconNotificationFound()
    }
}
```

The locations manager and the region is correct. The only problem is, that with this function nothing happens.
What can I do?

This is the code above:

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: UUID(uuidString: "E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0")!, identifier: "AirLocate")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Darf Standort genutzt werden?
    locationManager.delegate = self
    if (CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.authorizedWhenInUse) {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
}
```

Comment: What does the code look like inside BeaconNotificationFound()?  Do you know if this method even gets called?

Comment: Yes, the function is working. It tried it on another position.

Comment: OK, do you know that the BeaconNotificationFound() gets called in this case?  The issue may simply be that it does not, that you are not getting a region entry callback.  There are many, many reasons this may happen.  You probably need to show your code that sets up region monitoring, and requests location permissions in your app so we can be sure everything is right.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not getting callbacks to the `didEnterRegion` method.  A few things to check:

1. Make sure your Info.plist contains an entry like below, otherwise it won't be able to prompt you for location access: `<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key><string>This app needs to access your location so it can tell when you are near a beacon.</string>`
2. Make sure you are prompted for location access and you have actually granted it.  Check in Settings -> [Your app name] -> Location, and verify it says "ALLOW LOCATION ACCESS" has a checkmark that is not next to Never.
3. Make sure bluetooth is on.
4. Force a region exit by bringing your app to the foreground, and turning off the beacon for at least 60 seconds.  Once this is done, turn the beacon back on.
5. If none of the above works, use an off the shelf beacon detector app like [Locate](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) or AirLocate to verify it can see your beacon when transmitting.  If using one of these apps, you must configure your UUID in the app for detection.